# Increase speed of i/o in cpp for competitive coding

Tags: c++, performance, input, io

I am new to competitive programming. I was solving this question (https://www.codechef.com/problems/SUMTRIAN ) and its mentioned that this question requires fast input-output. I tested my function f for time and it took 1 microsec and i/o took 44505 microsec. Hence I believe I/O is the bottleneck

My solution is as follows

```
int fastscan()
{
    int x{};
    bool neg = false;
    register int c;
    x = 0;
    c = char();
    // for(;(c<48||c>57);c=char());
    if (c == '-') {
        neg = true;
        c = char();
    }
    for (; (c > 47 && c < 58); c = char())
        x = (x << 1) + (x << 3) + c - 48;
    if (neg)
        x *= -1;
    return x;
}

long long unsigned int f(array<int, 10005>& arr, long long int max, long long int cur, long long int n)
{
    if (cur + n >= max)
        return arr[n];
    long long int count{ 0 }, count1{ 0 };
    count = f(arr, max, cur + 1, n + cur);
    count1 = f(arr, max, cur + 1, n + cur + 1);
    count = count > count1 ? count : count1;
    return count + arr[n];
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    long long int t{};
    std::cin >> t;
    int n{};
    array<int, 10005> arr;
    while (t--) {
        n = fastscan();
        int temp = n * (n + 1) / 2;
        int max = temp;
        while (temp--) {
            arr[max - temp - 1] = fastscan();
        }
        return 0;
        long long int c{};
        c = f(arr, max, 1, 0);
        std::cout << c << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But on submission, it shows timelimit exceeded. one of the accepted solutions is as follows

```
#define mod 1000000007
#define ll long long
#define sc(x) scanf("%d",&x)
#define scll(x) scanf("%lld",&x)
#define pr(x) printf("%d\n",x)
#define prll(x) printf("%lld\n",x)
#define gc getchar_unlocked
#define pc putchar_unlocked    
inline int scan()
    {
        register int c = gc();
        int x = 0;
        for (; (c < 48 || c > 57); c = gc())
            ;
        for (; (c > 47 && c < 58); c = gc()) {
            x = (x << 1) + (x << 3) + c - 48;
        }
        return x;
    }
    
    inline void print(int a)
    {
        char snum[20];
        int i = 0;
        do {
            snum[i++] = a % 10 + 48;
            a = a / 10;
        } while (a != 0);
        i = i - 1;
        while (i >= 0)
            pc(snum[i--]);
        pc('\n');
    }
    int a[100][100];
    int sum(int n)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                a[i][j] = scan();
            }
        }
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (j == 0)
                    a[i][j] += a[i - 1][j];
                else if (j == i)
                    a[i][j] += a[i - 1][j - 1];
                else {
                    a[i][j] += max(a[i - 1][j], a[i - 1][j - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        int mm = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[n - 1][j] > mm)
                mm = a[n - 1][j];
        }
    
        return mm;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int t, n;
        t = scan();
        while (t--) {
    
            n = scan();
            print(sum(n));
        }
    }
```

the time measured on my machine for my code is less than the accepted code.... still the accepted code takes 0.01 sec to run on codechef and mine takes 3.01.
can someone pls help??

Comment: `fastscan` always returns the same value and `return 0` causes your outer while loop to only execute once?

Comment: Given the obvious **algorithmic** difference between your code and the accepted code (just compare your `f` function with the accepted `sum` function) why do you think the issue is I/O speed? Competitive coding sites are generally about picking the best algorithm, not about maximising I/O speed.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Horrendous as it is, I'm guessing that `char()` is actually a character reading macro (like `gc()` in the other code).

Comment: If you need to tweak I/O to make the code fast enough, there is almost always an algorithm that is even faster without doing that.

Comment: It's kind of cute that the accepted solution uses both `register` and `inline`, neither of which has had any effect on the execution time for literally decades. That is pure cargo-cult programming.

Comment: `register` no longer does anything, and `inline` is just a hint to the compiler that it should consider the function for inlining (which it does anyway), @john `char()` is probably shorter than `getchar_unlocked()` -- but you would think they could be creative enough not to duplicate a type-name `:)`

Comment: @AlanBirtles fastscan scans the input and returns it

Comment: I can't see any reading of input in `fastscan`, if you're using some nasty macros to make it do so then please provide a [mre]

Comment: Two suggestions. First, don't use magic numbers. `if (c < '0' || c > '9')` is much easier to read than `if (c < 48 || c > 57)` and will work correctly on systems where the hard-coded values don't.. Even better: `if (isdigit(c))` does the same thing, and could even be faster. Second, don't second-guess the compiler. `x = 10 * x + '0';` will work just as well as that hand-coded version, and is much easier to read.

Comment: I also agree that this problem is not I/O-bound, but for the fun of it: you are wasting time with `if (c == '-') `, as "all numbers are positive integers". You could also use the fact that all numbers are at most two digits ("between 0 and 99"). Also, what is the need for `long long` if the max value is 10,000? The 16-bit int is enough...